# Setting persistent readahead buffer other than in rc.local?

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB servers need a custom readahead setting for the devices that contain the database files.  I've added the following to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
blockdev --setra 32 /dev/md127
```

This works, but since `/etc/rc.local` is executed late in the boot process (specifically, after `mongod` starts), `mongod` complains about readahead being too high.  Is there another "correct" place to set this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is specifically for the database, just set the `readahead` as part of the upstart script by adding the blockdev command to `/etc/init/mongodb.conf` - then you can be sure it is set before each start of the database (which avoids confusion if you are changing it elsewhere for some reason in the meantime).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought of doing that but then I realized that the command would run every time the database is restarted.  Would this be safe to do?

Comment: Yes, no issue with doing that, though be aware that if you change that block device elsewhere for another workload, restarting the service will override that change - not an issue per se but something to keep in mind for the future

Comment: Thanks! These servers are dedicated to MongoDB, so no problems there.